# Python module that implements ftps

Tags: python, ftps

I was wondering if anybody could point me towards a free ftps module for python.

I am a complete newbie to python, but this is something I need for a work project. I need an ftps client to connect to a 3rd party ftps server.

thanks,

David.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you could use Twisted to implement FTPS by simply using its FTP implementation, but changing the [`FTPClient.connectFactory`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/protocols/ftp.py?rev=24609#L2186) attribute to be a function that does something with [`connectSSL`](https://twisted.org/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorSSL.connectSSL.html) rather than `connectTCP`.

Are you sure you want FTPS though?  [SFTP is a different, better, and much more popular protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025149/http://geekswithblogs.net/bvamsi/archive/2006/03/23/73147.aspx) these days: Twisted contains [an SFTP implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/conch/ssh/filetransfer.py?rev=24609) as well.

Comment: connectSSL can be used for implicit FTPS connection, but explicit FTPS (using AUTH command) is more popular than implicit FTPS. Still Twisted FTP implementation is a good start. Implementing AUTH (and co) together with altering DTP.connectionMade could be the next step.

Answer (score 8):

The ftplib module in Python version 2.7.1 has all of the functionality you will need, including TLS support.

http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib

Answer (score 4):

[M2Cypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) has a FTPS module.  From the [documentation](http://eikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.ftpslib-module.html):

```
>>> from M2Crypto import ftpslib
>>> f = ftpslib.FTP_TLS()
>>> f.connect('', 9021)
'220 spinnaker.dyndns.org M2Crypto (Medusa) FTP/TLS server v0.07 ready.'
>>> f.auth_tls()
>>> f.set_pasv(0)
>>> f.login('ftp', 'ngps@')
'230 Ok.'
>>> f.retrlines('LIST')
-rw-rw-r--   1 0        198          2326 Jul  3  1996 apache_pb.gif
drwxrwxr-x   7 0        198          1536 Oct 10  2000 manual
drwxrwxr-x   2 0        198           512 Oct 31  2000 modpy
drwxrwxr-x   2 0        198           512 Oct 31  2000 bobo
drwxr-xr-x   2 0        198         14336 May 28 15:54 postgresql
drwxr-xr-x   4 100      198           512 May 16 17:19 home
drwxr-xr-x   7 100      100          3584 Sep 23  2000 openacs
drwxr-xr-x  10 0        0             512 Aug  5  2000 python1.5
-rw-r--r--   1 100      198           326 Jul 29 03:29 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  12 0        0             512 May 31 17:08 python2.1
'226 Transfer complete'
>>> f.quit()
'221 Goodbye.'
>>>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to minimise use of third-party modules, you should be able to subclass the standard library's [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib).FTP class with the built-in (to Python) SSL support.  M2Crypto (or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), if you want to go that way) is the easier solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedProject) seems to have some implementation of FTPS (FTP over SSL) under the *conch* sub-project. I am no twisted expert, but [Glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13564/glyph), the *twisted* man himself, is listed in this site. Maybe by following his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80617/asychronous-programming-in-python-twisted#81456) to another question, you can find more details (good luck).

Comment: Thanks for the plug :).  But FTPS (FTP, but over SSL) is not the same thing as SFTP (file transfer over SSH, not really related to the FTP protocol at all).

Answer (score 2):

As for the server implementation you can take a look at pyftpdlib:
http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/
It includes a demo script implementing a working FTPS server:
http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/source/browse/trunk/demo/tls_ftpd.py

As for the client implementation I provided a patch which will be included in python 2.7 and 3.2.
http://bugs.python.org/issue2054

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself (yes, I just used Google and followed some links), but http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ seems to be the recommended solution. From a cursory glance, it's an SSH implementation in pure Python, which allows tunneling for things like FTP.

Update: a commenter pointed out that I mixed up sftp and ftps, sorry. I still suggest at least investigating Paramiko briefly to see if it matches the requirements.

Comment: sftp and ftps are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a free sftp client for windows so I ended up wrapping Putty's PSFTP using python's subprocess module.
I probably would have used the twisted implementation mentioned by Glyph if i'd known about it.

Anyway if your interested it's available at:

http://code.google.com/p/psftplib/