# how does a non-blocking event loop work?

Tags: language-agnostic, loops, twisted, blocking, nonblocking

Twisted has a "non-blocking" event loop.

I understand what a blocking event loop does (sort of, from the Wikipedia page) but can't figure out how a non-blocking one does.

Comment: This is similar to another question that I answered some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80617/asychronous-programming-in-python-twisted/81456#81456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (true)
    wait_for_events
    handle_events
```

Basically, non-blocking event loop utilizes device that allows for waiting for multiple events simultaneously (`select`/`poll` on UNIX, `WaitForMultipleEvents` on Windows, `epoll` on Linux `kqueue` on FreeBSD etc). In each iteration of main loop, events (file descriptors, timers etc) are registered in some kind of handle. Then, a function that waits for events (eg. `select`) is invoked. This typically returns all events that happened during invocation of that function. Finally, loop handles that events - typically by invoking callbacks associated with events.

For details, see implementation of libevent or some GUI toolkit event loops - GTK+ or Qt.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the system deal with the `select()`, I mean is it forked as a thread? or process? I can't wrap my head round how it can be non-blocking if it is not threaded or forked as a process...